# How does MySQL use memory when doing "select"?

Tags: mysql, memory, select

How does MySQL use memory when doing "select"? Is it right that MySQL can only load the selected columns and won't waste any memory on the rest of the columns?

e.g. I have a table with `1.article ID, 2.article content, 3.publish date, 4. edit time, 5. author ID, 6.with_image (binary, 1:yes, image attached, 0:no image).`

Article content is var(5000), and in fact the average size is about 2000.

Is it a good idea to keep a table in this way? Should I separate it from a article_ID & article_content table?

My idea is (if) MySQL can load only the selected columns and won't waste any memory on the rests. Then I'm going to use `SELECT article_id,author_id,publish_date,edit_time FROM thistable WHERE author_id=requirement ORDER BY publish_date DESC,edit_time DESC limit 50` to get the article_id list. Then use SELECT article,article_id WHERE article_id= the list, to get the final results.

Am I very wrong somehow? And what should be fixed? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me - yes the query will just retrieve the required columns from the table - I'm no expert on MySql but it will probably try and cache as much of the database as possible so you don't need to worry about memory on the server side. The client will only receive the queried data (queries are executed on the server and the result is passed back across the wire)

You don't need to split the table into two unless there's a good reason. Often having a crapload of columns on a single table is a reason to refactor the table into multiple tables, but currently with the number of columns it looks fine